# Something.php failed to open stream - yii

Tags: php, yii

I've recently moved my website from localhost to an online server (secretspygirl.com). Most of the website is working and I've confirmed that I am connected to my database. It appears I can access my database when I am making calls within the same model (i.e. if a table is called "foods", I've been able to call queries within the food model.) However, when I am trying to call "people" model within the favpeople controller I get an error.

```
include(people.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Here is where the error is occuring.

```
// this function redirects the user to the correct celebration page 
public function actionFavpeople()
{
     $favname = people::model()->favpeoplename();
     $peoplearray = people::model()->favpeople();

     // if the $peoplearray matches the hardcoded id of mom then the video becomes mom. 
     if ($peoplearray == Yii::app()->params['momid'])
     {
```

If you have any suggestions I would vastly appreciate. Is this something with uploading my website that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needs to be

```
 $favname = People::model()->favpeoplename();
 $peoplearray = People::model()->favpeople();
```

Some File Systems have case insensitive file name parsing meaning `People.php` is the same as `people.php`, like HFS+ on OS X, some OSes differentiate between the two i.e. they are two different files like most linux distros  ext2/3/4 on debian, CentOS etc; See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Letter_case_preservation for more info

You have probably used insensitive one for development and your server is sensitive.

Model files start with a capital letter, there fore calls also has to be in capital hence the above changes